# SQL vulnerable if input type = email check is enabled

Tags: email, vulnerability, injection

```
<input type="email"
class="form-control"
name="email address"
id="signinEmail"
placeholder="Email address"
aria-label="Email address"
value="INPUT"
required=""
data-msg="Please enter a valid email address."
data-error-class="u-has-error"
data-success-class="u-has-success"
aria-invalid="true"
aria-describedby="signinSrEmail-error">
```

*regarding above quoted input field (each param in a new line for easier reading purposes)*

Are those kind of input fields, which check specifically for valid_characters@valid.valid SQL-Injection vulnerable in any kind of way? Do I risk being exploited by implementing this kind of input field (which I discovered being used by someone else, so no credits go to me for creating this code.)?

I mean by trying to exploit with "*HARMFUL CODE*"@test.com won't work, the harmful code itself won't work as well, etc.

//NOTE:

```
<form class="js-validate mt-5" name="signin" action="/signin" method="post">
```

mentioned input field is member of said form class, which validates the SignIn via post-method, thus I think it's fairly secure implementing such code on a website, right?

Answer (score 2):

SQL injection is a server-side vulnerability. It has almost nothing to do with your client-side code. If you do all your validation on the front end, what happens when a malicious user decides to not use your front-end at all, but instead send requests directly to the server?

So, this does not protect against SQL injection at all. To properly protect against SQL injection, implement server-side protections. You can use a modern web framework and/or ORM that completely abstracts SQL away, or follow the [OWASP Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Comment: Sure so you're the opinion that via intercepting the Post request and replicating it with a tool like sqlmap this site is still exploitable?

Comment: In fact, I just tested it - and it doesn't work. :)

Comment: Why intercept the request when I can simply do `document.getElementById('signinEmail').type='text';` to disable local validation? I could send the parameters directly through curl, but that would be more annoying.

Comment: @Ángel appending this param at the end of the url or how is this supposed to be executed? Moreover, wouldn't getElementByXPath be the "wiser" choice?

Comment: No, I can execute that directly from the browser console. As you were so nice to include an id I took care of it. The way it is done is not relevant, though. I could use getElementByXPath, the browser inspector or edit a local copy of your page. You **need** to validate it server side. The will client side is controlled by the untrusted user (potential attacker).

Comment: @J.Doe it's not my opinion, it is a fact that frontend defenses will not work. Now, there may be other reasons your site may not appear vulnerable. But we have no idea how it is set up.

Comment: @multithr3at3d is it wise to upload / mention said site. As stated above, it's not my site, but I want to check if this one is safe as I'm planning to copy their security aspects.

Comment: @J.Doe unless you are copying their backend code, you likely won't find any security aspects to copy.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I, in fact, have their source code.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm a pentester, and I can 100% guarantee you that client-side-only validation does absolutely nothing to stop an attacker. You can either trust 3 security experts who all tell you the same thing and have credible sources to back up, or you can trust your own inability to perform a successful injection and use that as argument that you must be secure.